# Porting ClaimsAuthorizationManager to .NET Core

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, wif

I am preparing to port an .NET 4.6.1 application to .NET Core and struggle to find how the code permissions should be handled.
Currently i use custom **ClaimsAuthorizationManager**

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        var action = context.Action.First().Value;
        return context.Principal.HasClaim(resource,action);
    }
}
```

The **ClaimsAuthorizationManager** is configured to be used by application in app.config file.

Then each function that needs to have a code access permission has an **ClaimsPrincipalPermission** set with required permissions.
Now i would want to achieve same functionality in .NET Core and outside of MVC.
Anyone has any idea if and how is this achievable?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [authorization filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authorization-filters).

Comment: isnt that MVC core specific functionality ?

Comment: I guess you are right. Instead you can write your own [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0). This middleware should run after the user is authenticated.

Comment: Do you have any progress or alternative for this? I currently have the same problem.